# Separate rows in a 2d array into two groups based on string in row

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, array-filter

I need to group rows in a multidimensional array by the value of a sub-array which is not consistently found in the same column.

```
$array = [
    147 => [4, 'req'],
    199 => ['5', 'opt'],
    212 => [2, 5, 'req']
];
```

It needs to be split into these arrays.

Array 1:

```
[
    147 => [4, 'req'],
    212 => [2, 5, 'req'],
]
```

Array 2:

```
[
    199 => ['5', 'opt'],
]
```

I know of `array_filter()`, but can´t figure out the function inside `array_filter()` that gives me the desired result.

I tried

```
$req = array_filter($my_array, function ($v, $k) {
    return $v == 'req';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

I also tried

```
function filter_my_array($my_array, $search_term) {
  $new_array = array();
  foreach ($my_array as $subarray) {
    if (in_array($search_term, $subarray)) {
       $new_array[] = $subarray;
    }
  }
  return $new_array; 
} 
         
$req = filter_my_array($array, 'req');
```

Both approaches do not work.

Comment: `array_filter` does not split anything. It __filters__.

Comment: Are the values different each time or are they the same?

Comment: Your function works fine: https://3v4l.org/dRo69

Comment: Always "req" or "opt".

Comment: @u_mulder no because i lose [147], [199] and [212] (sorry I dont know how this is called).

Comment: Updated version: https://3v4l.org/ai5lH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two arrays with the help of filtering by necessary values. You can use array_filter function to it, but you should find a necessary value in each element that passed to array_filter function.

For example, finding 'req' value

```
$req = array_filter($my_array, function ($v) {
    return in_array('req', $v);
});
```

For example, finding 'opt' value

```
$opt = array_filter($my_array, function ($v) {
    return in_array('opt', $v);
});
```

I used in_array function to finding values because each element is an array that has different quantity of elements

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
function filter_my_array($my_array, $search_term) {
    $required_array = [];
    $filtered_array = [];
    foreach ($my_array as $key => $subarray) {
        $found_flag = false;
        foreach ($subarray as $cur_subarray) {
            if ($cur_subarray == $search_term) {
                $found_flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($found_flag == true) {
            $required_array[$key] = $subarray;
        } else {
            $filtered_array[$key] = $subarray;
        }
    }

    return [$required_array, $filtered_array];
}
```

To retrieve the required array and the filtered array, call the function as follows:

```
list($required_array, $filtered_array) = filter_my_array($my_array, 'req');
```

where $my_array holds the array in your example.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to populate variably named grouping arrays, it is not best practice. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/GaiEH)

```
$array = [
    147 => [4, 'req'],
    199 => ['5', 'opt'],
    212 => [2, 5, 'req']
];

foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    ${$row[array_key_last($row)]}[$key] = $row;
}
var_export($req);
var_export($opt);
```

Your IDE is going to struggle to realize that when these variables are accessed, these variables *actually* exist.

---

Instead, it would be more professional to deepen the array structure and use dynamic first level keys for grouping. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/GKasb)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $result[$row[array_key_last($row)]][$key] = $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

Regardless of which way you prefer, you should not use more than one loop  or call an iterating function (`array_filter()`) more than once.